# Automatically get a value from a log in based website daily

Tags: browser, automation

I have an online share trading account in which I own a number of shares. I want to be able to get the total portfolio value automatically daily. Unfortunately my broker doesn't have an API interface. I think it should be possible to get the value using browser automation such Selenium. I can then get the value through the id of the div tag. Does anybody know what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs supports a spreadsheet formula called [GoogleFinance](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en). I presume it works for stock markets around the world. I tried the below formula for Dr. Reddy's Laboratories listed in the Bombay Stock Exchange (BSE)

=GoogleFinance(500124,"price")

[The scrip code 500124 represents Dr. Reddy's Laboratories](http://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/8387/14/14_annexure%20%20i.pdf). You can use a [Google Docs sheet to track stocks](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/09/12/track-stock-mf-portfolio-google-docs/).